# Powershell - cut domain name from FQDN

Tags: string, powershell, cut

I would like to list all Session Hosts in all Collections, convert to string. I get this with:

```
$SHs = (Get-RDSessionCollection -ConnectionBroker $CB | Select-Object -Property collectionname | ForEach-Object  -Process { Get-RDSessionHost -ConnectionBroker $CB -CollectionName $_.collectionname }) |select SessionHost  |Out-String
```

Output:

```
SessionHost                
-----------
SH1.contoso.com
SH2.contoso.com
SH3.contoso.com
```

Now  I would like cut domain name .contoso.com from fqdn.

```
foreach ($SH in $SHs){ 

$SH = $SH.Substring(0,$SH.Length-12)
$SH
}
```

but the output still:

```
SessionHost                
-----------
SH1.contoso.com
SH2.contoso.com
SH3.contoso.com
```

Desired Output is:

```
SH1
SH2
SH3
```

Edit: I tried followings codes (thx for help):

```
$SH = ($SH -split "\.")[0]
```

and

```
$SH = ($SH -split '\.' | Select -first 1) -join '.'
```

and I receive only :

```
SH01
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Not reproducible, `$Vmname` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to edit this variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a terminal server to test this should work actually:

```
$SHs = (
    Get-RDSessionCollection -ConnectionBroker $CB | 
        Select-Object -Property collectionname | 
            ForEach-Object -Process { 
                Get-RDSessionHost -ConnectionBroker $CB -CollectionName $_.collectionname 
            }
    ) | 
    Select-Object -Property SessionHost 

foreach ($SH in $SHs.SessionHost) { 
    ($SH -split "\.")[0]
}
```

Comment: yeahh ... finally.  ;-)  :-D